# opengl set color of 'unrendered' space

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I want to specify a color for the space on the screen that is unrendered (right now, where my object ARENT, it is just black). Is there a way I can change this to another color (or even better, a texture?)

I am using c if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [glClearColor](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClearColor.xml). Though, I will add that no pixel on the screen is really "unrendered" so what you are wanting to do is set the default value that sits in the buffer until one of your objects renders over it.

Comment: thanks for the explanation too :) like I said, I am new, just kind of got thrown into it by one of my profs

Comment: If you like the answer, be sure to accept it. Also, consider adding the "homework" tag if this is related to that.

Comment: ya, I am waiting til I can accept it lol. and will do next time ;)